# how to calculate percentage of sales and return in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have 10 columns in a table as below:

```
(transaction id, customer id, transaction date, product subcategory,
 product category, quantity, rate, tax, total amount and store type.)
```

where returns are in negative value of (quantity,rate, tax and total amount) i have to calculate

***what is percentage of sales and returns by product sub category?***

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  This sounds like a basic `GROUP BY` query, so you should also show your attempt.

Comment: "select pro_subcat,(sum(qty)*100)/rate as salepercentage, (sum(qty)*100)/qty as returnpercentage  from Tb2_trans group by pro_subcat,rate,qty" @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like e.g.:

```
  SELECT productsubcategory, SUM(CASE WHEN quantity < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0)/COUNT(*)
  FROM t
  GROUP BY productsubcategory
```

That will give a ratio of the returns to all transactions. If you want it on a per-item basis rather than a per-transaction basis it would be more like:

```
  SELECT productsubcategory, SUM(CASE WHEN quantity < 0 THEN -quantity ELSE 0)/SUM(ABS(quantity))
  FROM t
  GROUP BY productsubcategory
```

But be careful how you treat quantities; i've guess that "sell 20 biscuits, return 15 biscuits" is a total of 35 product movements, 15 of which are returns. I don't know if you want a conclusion of "15/20ths (75%) of biscuits were returned" in which case make the returns a percentage of the sales, not a percentage of the sales+returns

Comment: i tried your tried both query but the the results are just the product sub categories, no percentage value are shown in output. Yes, i want the conclusion as percentage returns on sales.

Comment: The calculated column is the percentage. This here in my query:`SUM(CASE WHEN quantity < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0)/COUNT(*)` - if there are 20 rows then count(*) is 20. If half of them are negative then sum(case when <0..) returns 10, 10/20 is 0.5 or 50 percent.  Multiply it by 100 if you want your percentage as E.g. 70.9 rather than 0.709